# web2py Formatting list items in views

Tags: python, web2py

**Synopsis:**
I want to see something like this:

```
Regular Loan      Loan
Appliances Loan   Loan
Monthly Dues      Contribution
HELP              Contribution
```

... but I am getting this instead:

```
Regular Loan     <Set Loan>
Appliances Loan  <Set Loan>
Monthly Dues     <Set Contribution>
HELP             <Set Contribution>
```

How do I make the `<Set Loan>` and `<Set Contribution>` to just `Loan` and `Contribution`?

```
#controller
def get_service_name(type_id=int):
    type_item = db(db.service_types.id==type_id).select()
    return type_item[0].type_name

def list_services():
    rows = db(db.services).select()
    types = []
    for s in rows:
        types.append(db(get_service_name(s.service_type)))
    return locals()
```

```
#view
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>
    Services
</h1>
{{i = -1}}
{{for service in rows:}}
{{i = i +1}}
<tr><span>{{=service.service_name}}</span><span>{{=types[i]}}</span></tr><br>
{{pass}}
```

**Edit 1**

```
#db.py
db.define_table('service_types',
            Field('type_name', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_SLUG()]),
            format='%(type_name)s',
)

db.define_table('services',
            Field('service_name',requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(),IS_NOT_IN_DB(db,'services.service_name')]),
            Field('service_type','reference service_types',requires=IS_IN_DB(db,db.service_types.id,
                                                                            '%(type_name)s',
                                                                            error_message='not in table',
                                                                            zero=None))
)
```

Comment: You may want to add some sample code which populates your database.

Comment: tfv, there's none, I just use the database administration to add sample data.

Comment: Then maybe you want to tell us about the structure of the tables: You have a table service_types with fields id and type_name? An another table services?

Comment: included the table structure in Edit 1

Comment: I have included your table definitions and added a service and a service type manually (you may also want to include data in you code, you could insert data in the code). When I look at the page http://192.168.178.72:8000/test/default/list_services , everything looks fine.

Comment: I don't see anything seriously wrong with the code either. What I don't understand is this code in the view `{{=types[i]}}` includes the symbols <Set xxx> when rendering the value. It has nothing to do with the underlying database data. Why can't it just output xxx?  What is doing this,  web2py or python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db(query)` returns a DAL `Set` object. I think instead, you want:

```
types.append(get_service_name(s.service_type))
```

But, in fact, it is simpler than that, as you can use [recursive selects](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Recursive-selects) to have the DAL select from the `service_types` table automatically (i.e., no need for the `get_service_name` function).

```
def list_services():
    rows = db(db.services).select()
    return dict(rows=rows)
```

In the view:

```
{{for service in rows:}}
<tr>
  <span>{{=service.service_name}}</span>
  <span>{{=service.service_type.type_name}}</span>
</tr><br>
{{pass}}
```

Note, this approach (as well as you original code) is somewhat inefficient, as it does an additional database select for each record. If there are many records, you may instead want to do a join:

```
def list_services():
    rows = db(db.services.service_type == db.service_types.id).select(
        db.services.service_name, db.service_types.type_name)
    return dict(rows=rows)
```

Then in the view:

```
{{for row in rows:}}
<tr>
  <span>{{=row.services.service_name}}</span>
  <span>{{=row.service_types.type_name}}</span>
</tr><br>
{{pass}}
```

The above approach requires only a single query.

Comment: Matter of fact fact I  do believe a join is what I am looking for. I never wanted to do the separate select for type_names in the first place, being an inefficient additional db select.  I'll test your code and report back.

Comment: This answered my question, and offered an alternative spot on to what I really wanted to do.